# In Reactjs using stripe i need to include netbanking, UPI, debitcard and credit card payment

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

In React js I need to include netbanking, UPI, debitcard and credit card payment. As per Stripe docs I have included credit card payment. But I am not able to get any reference for internet banking, UPI. please suggest me if any sample is available.

Thanks in Advance.

I am able to display below payment page format

[image]

The above pic it displays cardnumber, expiry date and cvv in same line. Is there anyway to display first Row card number and in second Row expiry and CVV ? and also do we can add labels?

PaymetProvider: -

```
import React from 'react'
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import MyCheckoutForm from './CheckOutForm';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_51JWBuuSB2HdD9HME7g...sFfz8O6bY00d1NcxaxX');

export default function PaymentProvider() {
    return (
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <MyCheckoutForm />
      </Elements>
    );
  };
```

CheckOutForm: -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
import axios from 'axios'

const CARD_OPTIONS = {
    iconStyle: "solid",
    style: {
        base: {
            iconColor: "#c4f0ff",
            color: "#fff",
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontFamily: "Roboto, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif",
            fontSize: "16px",
            fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
            ":-webkit-autofill": { color: "#fce883" },
            "::placeholder": { color: "#87bbfd" }
        },
        invalid: {
            iconColor: "#ffc7ee",
            color: "#ffc7ee"
        }
    }
}

export default function MyCheckoutForm() {
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)
    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)

        })

        if (!error) {
            try {
                const { id } = paymentMethod
                const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/payment", {
                    amount: 1000,
                    id
                })

                if (response.data.success) {
                    console.log("Payment successful")
                    setSuccess(true)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error: ", error)
            }    
        } else {
            console.log("error", error.message)
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            {!success ? 
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <fieldset className="FormGroup">
                        <div className="FormRow">
                            <CardElement options={CARD_OPTIONS} />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <button className="Stripebutton"> Pay</button>
                </form>
            :
                <div>
                    <h2>You just bought a sweet </h2>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Stripe doesn't support UPI and supports debiting bank accounts only in certain countries. See https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/overview for the full list.

Comment: And sure you can definitely split the number/CVC/expiry to multiple lines. Look into the other Element types and the "Split Card Elements" example for react-stripe-js https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-official-q1loc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks I will look into splitting card number/cvc/expiry date

Comment: When we enter card number, for example 4242 Visa, for MC card number starts with 2 or 5, it is not displaying visa img/MC on left or right side of the card number field.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=cardNumber#elements_create-options-showIcon .